# Laravel 5.4 - Eloquent : Join 3 tables and return 1 collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I recently started using laravel and having some issues with eloquent join .

I want to join 3 tables :

- User (**id**)
- UserBills (**id** , user_id , **company_id** , **account**)
- Bills (id , **company_id** , **account** , amount)

I start with the user id (e.g=1)

From that i want to query UserBills and find all UB where the user_id = id
Next i want to query bills and find all bills where the bill company_id and account match UserBills

Basically i want to find all the bills that belong to that specific user . Bills does not have user_id however and must check with UserBills(company_id and account)

// This return all user bills with id = user_id

```
$results = User::findOrFail(1);
$ub = $results->user_bills;
```

From there , i have no idea how to join the bills or get the collection . Any help would be much appreciated.

Models (might be wrong)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Eloquent;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [

        'name', 
        'email', 
        'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function user_bills()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserBills', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

UserBills

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserBills extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'ub';

    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'user_id',
        'company_id',
        'account',
    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User' , 'id' , 'user_id');
    }

}
```

Bills :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bills extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'bills';

    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'company_id',
        'account',
        'period', 
        'amount',
    ];

    public function user_bills()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\UserBills');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your solution in the docs of [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) if your `UserBills` hasMany `Bills`.
I can't test this code right now, so you can see it as an example:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {

   ...

  public function Bills()
  {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\UserBills', 'App\Bills');
  }

}
```

Now you can get all bills of the user with

```
$User = User::findOrFail(1);
$Bills = $User->Bills()->get(); // collection with bills of your user instance
```

### Edit #1

You should add a `bill_id` into the UserBills table `ub`.
Now you can try this code

```
class User extends Authenticatable {

  ...

  public function getBillsAttribute() {
    $user_id = $this->id;

    return App\Bills::rightJoin('ub', function($join) use ($user_id) {
      $join->on('ub.bill_id', '=', 'bills.id')
           ->where('ub.user_id', '=', $user_id);
    })->get();
  }

}
```

Use it like that

```
$User = User::findOrFail(1);
$Bills = $User->Bills; // collection with bills of your user instance
```

Comment: public function Bills()
 {
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Bills', 'App\UserBills', 'id', 'id', 'id');
 }

Comment: is it possible to use eloquent only instead of query ?

Comment: i think the issue with the Bills eloquent function are the parameters

Comment: The [Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) is a part of eloquent. I don't find another way to solve this.